# HTML page Validation including php and MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I Want to develop a simple HTML page with 3 text fields

UniqueID:
FirstName:
LastName:

These 3 fields are columns in MySql database table , so when ever any user enters UniqueID , the page should get connected to Database (using php) checks for the UniqueID if it exists in Database the remaining columns need to be populated in HTML page(these retrieved values FirstName & Last Name should not be able to modify by user), if the UniqueID doesn't exist in the DB the user should get a chance to fill FirstName & LastName and then submit the values to the Database.

Comment: And what do you want from us - write you all the codez?

Comment: I want to develop a google again Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Should I sent you a quotation?

Answer (score 0):

You simply can do it with this:

**dbconnect.php**

```
<?php
//connect to mysql database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456pass", "database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

**index.php**

```
    <?php
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    //set validation error flag as false
    $error = false;

    //check if form is submitted
    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        $uniqueid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['uniqueid']);
        $firstn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstn']);
        $lastn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastn']);

        //name can contain only alpha characters and space
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $firstn . " " . $lastn)) {
            $error = true;
            $name_error = "Name must contain only alphabets and space";
        }
        if (empty(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UniqueID='" . $uniqueid . "'"))) {
        $error = true;
        $uniqueid_error = "The UniqueID " . $uniqueid . " already exists!";
        }

        if (!$error) {
            if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(UniqueID,FirstName,LastName) VALUES('" . $uniqueid . "', '" . $firstn . "', '" . $lastn . "')")) {
                $successmsg = "Successfully Registered!";
            } else {
                $errormsg = "Error in registering...Please try again later!";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 well">
                <form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="registerform">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Register</legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Unique ID</label>
                            <input type="text" name="uniqueid" placeholder="Enter The UniqueID" required value="<?php if($error) echo $uniqueid; ?>" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($uniqueid_error)) echo $uniqueid_error; ?></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstn" placeholder="First Name" required value="<?php if($error) echo $firstn; ?>" class="form-control" />Sign Up
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastn" placeholder="Last Name" required class="form-control" />
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($name_error)) echo $name_error; ?></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                <span class="text-success"><?php if (isset($successmsg)) { echo $successmsg; } ?></span>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In **index.php** replace `users(UniqueID,FirstName,LastName)` with the table name and the columns name. In **dbconnect.php** replace `"123456pass", "database"` with the password of mysql and the database name